# Htaccess how to not redirect to root if in specific directory

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

I have the following code in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !_assets/ajax
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ index.php [L]
```

I thought and hoped this would exclude the `_assets` directory from being redirected to the root, but without success.

All directories are being redirected to the root, where I explode the URI to get the respective pages (in PHP). The htaccess file is actualy working as the right content is being displayed, according to the uri.

So to be briefly, my ajax calls do not work because of this.

How can can I make this work?

I'm using WAMP and created a **virtual host** named `http://project.localhost`.

Comment: `%{REQUEST_URI}` always contains an _absolute_ path, even when used inside `.htaccess` style files. That means you have to test against the leading slash too: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/_assets/ajax`

Comment: What is an example of AJAX request? Are there more rules or any other .htaccess in your system?

Comment: It is an ajax request to post some data, and I read about putting an .htaccess with `RewriteEngine Off`in the directory to exclude it. But without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this is with a simple rewrite rule that you put before any other rewrite rules.

```
RewriteRule ^/_assets/ajax/ - [L]
```

It say to take every URL that matches the regex `^/_assets/ajax/` (that is, everything in that directory), don't rewrite it, and stop processing the .htaccess file.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I tried putting it before the `RewriteRule` & the `RewriteCond`. Without success

Comment: Hmm, that's odd, please try `RewriteRule _assets/ajax/.* - [L]`. If that doesn't work, I don't know either.

Comment: Also without success :\

Comment: Are you sure htaccess is actually working? That is the only thing that I can thing of that could cause this.

Comment: I guess so, I'm currently in the path `nl/admin/news`, and the right content is being loaded. Also the "content" for the ajax request is being loaded, but not found obviously. Do I have to restart my wamp server to let it work?

Comment: You shouldn't need to restart your WAMP stack, but are you perhaps using it via localhost? If that is the case, htaccess won't work.

Comment: Yes, I created a vhost for my project: `http://project.localhost/nl/admin/news` But the uri is working, so that's actualy proof that htaccess does work...

Comment: Sorry, then I don't know how to solve your issue, though it might be good to include some things in your question (that you're running WAMP with a vhost and that htaccess is actually working). Good luck fixing this.

Comment: Wow, I managed to make it work when I placed the ajax directory into the root of the project. I tested it even without the rewriteCond and it still worked then.